# Plotting function $f(x,y,z)$

Tags: calculus, multivariable-calculus, optimization, graphing-functions

Is there a graphing program that can be used to plot a function $f(x,y,z)$? I've been looking all over the internet but can't seem to find one. Ideally, I want to use it to classify the critical points of a function as a verification.

Comment: The best I know of is this: https://www.monroecc.edu/faculty/paulseeburger/calcnsf/CalcPlot3D/

Comment: @Hadi I think that tool is just for $f(x,y)$? Forgive me if I'm wrong.

MATHBOI, I'm wondering what you're are envisaging: it's difficult to plot things in 3 dimensions, let alone 4. Perhaps you can use [Desmos to plot it in 3D](https://www.desmos.com/calculator/nqom2ih05g) and put the third dependent variable on a slider so you'd be viewing cross-sections of the 4D plot?

Comment: Unfortunately, a function $f(x, y, z)$ gives rise to a four-dimensional object. Explicitly, this object is described by the set $\{(x, y, z, f(x, y, z)) \,|\, x, y, z \text{ are in the domain of } f\}.$ Luckily, for functions of two-variables, the surface $z = f(x, y)$ can be graphed easily on [Geogebra](https://www.geogebra.org/3d?lang=en); you don't even need to write $z.$ For instance, to graph the elliptic paraboloid $f(x, y) = x^2 + y^2,$ simply type in $x^2 + y^2.$

Comment: I am also familiar with GeoGebra Classic (free tool) and will recommend it for 3D Graphics...

Comment: What about MATLAB slice: https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/slice.html ?